# How to compute covariance matrix faster in C?

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra

I have around 1000,000 vectors of length 360. I need to find covariance matrix for each vector and then add them up. So I subtract the mean from each vector and do the outer cross product for each vector and then add them up. Since covariance matrix is symmetric, I run the loop 1000,1000*360! times and in each loop, I do 2 subtraction, 1 multiplication and 1 addition.
It takes around 55 sec to execute it. Is there any other method to do it faster?

Comment: Are you rolling your own method for finding the covariance matrix or are you using a library?  Has google-fu found you any open source libraries for this operation?

Comment: @Davidann Thank u for your reply.But I cannot import any external library.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It seems that [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fast%20covariance%20matrix%20calculation) has something to say about it.

Comment: you need to do the loop only 500 * 999 x 360 times, reason the co-variance matrix is symmetric